# BottomSheetDialog with transparent background

Tags: android

I would like to display a bottom sheet dialog less wide than the screen width.

For instance, the Share option from Google Play Music on a Nexus 9.

[image: the Share option from Google Play Music on a Nexus 9]

Do you know how to achieve this ?

For now I just succed to reduce the width of the sheet content but the background is still at the screen width and display a white background.

Some code:

build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
```

MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    mBottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
    mBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(R.layout.sheet_test);
    mBottomSheetDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            mBottomSheetDialog = null;
        }
    });
    mBottomSheetDialog.show();
}
```

sheet_test

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:text="Some Text"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#ddd" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:text="Some Text" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#ddd" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: please share some Code :)

Comment: What version of the Design Library are you using? Have you tried it with the latest (23.3.0)?

Comment: I think you just need to make the parent activity transparent. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android

Comment: Ok, so I have to add an activity just to show my bottom sheet view ? For now, I create my BottomSheetDialog from an activity displaying some business information, so not transparent.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm stuck on this as well.

Comment: Badly, I did not have the time to test but I think, Madushan answer is the good one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, I figured out 2 solutions.

**Best one:**

Create an activity with transparent background just for your bottom sheet.
Implement your own layout with a coordinator layout and a bottom sheet.
Set the margin you want.
Set the content you want.

Not tested yet.

**Lazy one:**

Extends [BottomSheetDialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialogFragment.html), in `onActivityCreated` add:

```
    Resources resources = getResources();

    // Set margin for Landscape Mode. Maybe a more elegant solution will be to implements our own bottom sheet with our own margins.
    if (resources.getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        assert getView() != null;
        View parent = (View) getView().getParent();
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) parent.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setMargins(
                resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.bottom_sheet_margin_left), // 64dp
                0,
                resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.bottom_sheet_margin_right), // 64dp
                0
        );
        parent.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
```

Comment: this one works but not for bottomMargin, unfortunately. Any trick to do so? @Pierre

Comment: @MihirPatel if you want to add a bottom padding, why dont youbuse the first one and give the layout some bottom margin? Or what about a dialog?

Answer (score 217):

This worked for me when using `BottomSheetDialogFragment`:

```
public class CustomDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(BottomSheetDialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.CustomBottomSheetDialogTheme);
  }
  
  ...
}
```

Also add this to your `styles.xml`

```
<style name="CustomBottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/CustomBottomSheetStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomBottomSheetStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Option 2:

```
override fun getTheme() = R.style.CustomBottomSheetDialogTheme
```

Comment: Just a note for others, the setStyle call doesn't work inside of the onCreateView method.  Works just fine when used like the example above.  Thanks for the solution!

Comment: this must be selected as answer, works like a charm!

Comment: i tried a lot of solutions and this is the only that works for me, thanks a lot :D

Comment: This works like a charm, it's right. I would suggest to add an update to use the new [`Theme.MaterialComponents`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/res/values/themes.xml): `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.BottomSheetDialog` for the Theme in this case.

Comment: Why does this only work in onCreate and not onCreateView?

Comment: @Mr.Drew 
The `onCreate()` method in a Fragment is called after the Activity's `onAttachFragment()` but before that Fragment's `onCreateView()`.
In this method, you can assign variables that don't involve the View hierarchy (i.e. non-graphical initialization). The `onCreateView()` is called after `onCreate()` and here we attach our view for the dialog. The dialog itself has a frame that is already created in `onCreate()`. Hence that frame can only be removed in the `onCreate()` method.

Answer (score 102):

BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog =new BottomSheetDialog(this,R.style.SheetDialog);

```
<style name="SheetDialog" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <!--<item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>-->
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">     @android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.3</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: It would be better if you can explain few items

Comment: This comprehensive set of settings works, but I selected a more simple answer of @Gnzlt.

Comment: The answer is helpful :)

Comment: This should be the right one.

Answer (score 65):

**This is simplest solution for set transparent background of BottomSheetDialogFragment**

It makes use of the following line of code:

```
 ((View) contentView.getParent()).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
```

Example in context:

```
public class ShareOneTouchAlertNewBottom extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
    @Override
    public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style) {
        super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
        View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet, null);
        dialog.setContentView(contentView);

        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) ((View) contentView.getParent())
                .getLayoutParams();
        CoordinatorLayout.Behavior behavior = params.getBehavior();
        ((View) contentView.getParent()).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using `Color.TRANSPARENT` rather than `getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)`

Comment: When overriding setupDialog method in your custom bottomsheet, ensure that you are not overriding `onCreateView` in it. `setupDialog` is essentially doing the job of `onCreateView` here.

Answer (score 31):

Sorry got it late here is what you are looking for upvote if u have done it successfully

```
  @Override    
  public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ((View) getView().getParent()).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}
```

Add this line in bottom sheet dialog fragment's on activity created. This will do the trick

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewParent android.view.View.getParent()' on a null object reference
        at com.maetimes.android.pokekara.section.sing.view.TransparentBottomFragment.onActivityCreated(TransparentBottomFragment.java:39)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2460)

Comment: After applying around 10 solutions this one worked for me.

Answer (score 29):

The following function override worked in a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` implementation:

```
class MyTopicBottomSheet : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {


    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {

       return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState).apply {
           // window?.setDimAmount(0.2f) // Set dim amount here
           setOnShowListener {
            val bottomSheet = findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet) as FrameLayout
            bottomSheet.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent)
           }
       }
    }

    // Rest of your class here
}
```

Answer (score 20):

Following the idea from [Marco RS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58142765/4664567) (that for me was the only solution at all that works), you can create a clean extension and apply wherever you want on your dialogs.

Extension:

```
fun BottomSheetDialogFragment.setTransparentBackground() {
    dialog?.apply {
        setOnShowListener {
            val bottomSheet = findViewById<View?>(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet)
            bottomSheet?.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent)
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    setTransparentBackground()
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Bit of a hack but it works for making background transparent. Obviously you can replace the 'transparent' with whatever colour you want.

```
mBottomSheetDialog.getWindow().findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet).setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Answer (score 11):

There are several *hackish* ways to do it. The way I solved this issue is the recommended way. Let's understand why?

In the docs, it's mentioned that

> Modal bottom sheet. This is a version of DialogFragment that shows a bottom sheet using BottomSheetDialog instead of a floating dialog.

This means there should be a method that `BottomSheetDialogFragment` uses to replace the default `Dialog` with a `BottomSheetDialog`.

The only method `BottomSheetDialogFragment` overrides is `onCreateDialog()`. So we're gonna use this public method to override our dialog style.

**Recommended Method**

In the fragment that extends `BottomSheetDialogFragment` overrDide `onCreateDialog()` which is a public method exposed by `BottomSheetDialogFragment` itself.

```kotlin
    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, R.style.BottomSheetDialog)
        return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)
    }
```

besides that, in `themes.xml` override `BottomSheetDialog` theme and add transparent background.

```xml
    <style name="BottomSheetDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/BottomSheetModal</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BottomSheetModal" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

More about:

- `BottomSheetDialogFragment`: [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetDialogFragment)
- `onCreateDialog`: [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetDialogFragment#onCreateDialog(android.os.Bundle))
- theming the `BottomSheetDialog`: [here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-sheet-dialog-fragment)

Comment: This is the best, recommended and the most updated solution

Answer (score 7):

I had same problem, nothing helped. 
Used this code to solve the problem:

```
  override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    val bottomSheet = (view!!.parent as View)
    bottomSheet.backgroundTintMode = PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR
    bottomSheet.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.TRANSPARENT)
    bottomSheet.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
}
```

P.S. com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09

Comment: This worked but I also had to add `setElevation(0)` to remove shadows.

Answer (score 6):

BottomSheetDialog will get the `R.attr.bottomSheetDialogTheme` style from your context's theme, or else use the default `R.style.Theme_Design_Light_BottomSheetDialog`.

The layout xml of BottomSheetDialog is [R.layout.design_bottom_sheet_dialog](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/res/layout/design_bottom_sheet_dialog.xml). The main content is a FrameLayout with id/design_bottom_sheet whose style is `?attr/bottomSheetStyle`.

If you extends a style with parent `Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog` then all your default attrs like `colorPrimary`, `colorAccent` may be overrided. Thus ThemeOverlay is recommended to be used in View Theme tree. You should extend a style from `ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light.BottomSheetDialog` like this:

```xml
<style name="Widget.Test.ButtonSheetDialogTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/Widget.Test.BottomSheet.Modal</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.Test.BottomSheet.Modal" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

You have to extend a style from `Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomSheet.Modal`, because the default style contains these:

```xml
<style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomSheet" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">?attr/colorSurface</item>
    ....
</style>
```

BottomSheetDialog's background is decided both by `android:background` and `backgroundTint`. But I am not sure why backgroundTint is effective while android:background is null. ??

For more knowledge about Android Theme:

- [Android Styling: themes overlay](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/android-styling-themes-overlay-1ffd57745207)

Answer (score 5):

Late answer, but faced this problem myself and found better solution then any of suggested.

You can wrap your sheet layout with another layout with transparent background and add margin from it (16dp here):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    >
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="16dp">

        ....
```

Then add transparent background to your sheet like in Gnzlt [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46469709/9017458):

```
<style name="CustomBottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/CustomBottomSheetStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomBottomSheetStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

And voila, don't need another activity.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.. Oncreate Dialog get the window set color

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    if(dialog.getWindow() !=null){
        dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }
    return dialog;
}
```

Comment: the one also apply to BottomSheetDialog, perfect

Answer (score 3):

use "setOnShowListener" for your dialog instance, like this in kotlin:

```
        yourDialogInstance.setOnShowListener {

        //this line transparent your dialog background
        (dialogView.parent as ViewGroup).background = 
             ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)

        }
```

complete code in kotlin :

```
BottomSheetDialog(this).apply {

val dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    .inflate(R.layout.your_dialog_layout, null, false)

setContentView(dialogView)

setOnShowListener {
    (dialogView.parent as ViewGroup).background = 
             ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)
}

show()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding `android:background` or `android:colorBackground` property will not make the bottom sheet transparent as suggested by many answers!

Adding, `backgroundTint` to sheetStyle is the key to making bottomsheet transparent.

**Eg:**

```
  <style name="BottomSheetDialog" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/BottomSheetStyle</item>
  </style>

  <!--The following piece is key, -->

  <style name="BottomSheetStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@android:color/transparent</item>
  </style>
```

Pass this style as second parameter while creating the BottomSheetDialog in java or kt.

**Eg:**

```
BottomSheetDialog(context, R.style.BottomSheetDialog)
```

**Resource:** 
A good resource to learn more about BottomSheet https://m2.material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-sheet-dialog-fragment

Comment: This did not work for me until I added "android:backgroundTint" instead of "backgroundTint"

Answer (score 2):

This is your answer :D

```
View contentView=LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.bs_add_event,null);
    mBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(contentView);

    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) ((View) contentView.getParent()).getLayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(50,50,50,50); // set margin as your wish.
```

and also change  `android:layout_width="100dp"  in nestedScroolView` to
 `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

Answer (score 2):

**1. Firstly Add Style in your theme:**

```
   <style name="MyTransparentBottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
       <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
       <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
   </style>
```

**2. Then attach above style with BottomSheetDialogFragment same as below :**

```
   @Override
   public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return new BottomSheetDialog(getContext(),R.style.MyTransparentBottomSheetDialogTheme);
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

1 - Initialize the bottom sheet dialog this way.

```
BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(YourActivity.this, R.style.BottomSheetDialog);
```

2 - Add this style as suggested by Gnzlt.

```
<style name="BottomSheetDialog" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/BottomSheetDialogStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="BottomSheetDialogStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but I still answer the question and hope it useful.
By default, the layout specified in `onCreateView()` method will be added to a `FrameLayout` with white background by `BottomSheetDialogFragment`. Therefor, you should set the FrameLayout's background to transparent in `onStart()` method.

```
class YourDialog() : BaseBottomDialog() {
   
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_your_dialog, container, false)
    }
    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        (view!!.parent as View).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found that I needed to use a variant on the accepted answer, by updating to MaterialComponents to make compatible with AndroidX as well as adding "backgroundTint" as transparent as well:

```
<style name="BottomSheetDialog" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/BottomSheetDialogStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="BottomSheetDialogStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Apply the "BottomSheetDialog" style to the fragment as per the original answer:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(BottomSheetDialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.BottomSheetDialog);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Add the following code in your style.xml

```
<style name="BottomDialogStyle" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/CustomBottomSheetStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomBottomSheetStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Also, update the onCreate

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.BottomDialogStyle)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using BottomSheetBehavior then use the below code on collapse and Expand states

```
behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);             ((View)getParent()).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(<your desire color>));
```

and

```
behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED); ((View).getParent()).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
```

Also, use

```
 behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {
                    ((View) mScrollview.getParent()).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
                // React to dragging events  
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all your BottomSheets inherit that behavior, just do as follows:

```
<style name="Theme.InstaDownloader" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
       ...
        <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/BottomSheetTheme</item>
       ...
 </style>

 <style name="BottomSheetTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/BottomSheetStyle</item>
 </style>

 <style name="BottomSheetStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
 </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me below worked:

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    (view.parent as? View)?.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <style name="BaseBottomSheetDialogTrasn" parent="@style/Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/BottomSheetTrans</item>
</style>


<style name="BottomSheetDialogThemeTrans" parent="BaseBottomSheetDialogTrasn">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/white</item>
</style>


 <style name="BottomSheetTrans" parent="@style/Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

And finally add the parameter in BottomSheetDialog(context,R.style.BottomSheetDialogThemeTrans)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm much late but in kotlin the thing that really helped me out is adding this line in your fragment in onCreate():

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL,R.style.CustomBottomSheetDialog)
}
```

And in styles():

```
  <style name="CustomBottomSheetDialog" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog"> 
  <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/bottomSheetStyleWrapper       
  </item>
  </style>
  <style name="bottomSheetStyleWrapper" 
  parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
  <item
name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
  </style>
```

Works perfectly fine for me.