# BottomSheetDialog not rounding top corners correctly in Android

Tags: java, android, android-bottomsheetdialog

I have a custom `BottomSheetDialog` and for its layout i created drawable which has top corners rounded rectangle. `BottomSheetDialog` layout background is a `Linearlayout` and i applied drawable to the layout.Top corners of the bottom sheet rounding correctly but there is a another layout bottom of the Linear Layout which is not rounded (square and white see below picture) and it is not in the layout.xml file. its like rounded rectangle on top of a square.I couldn't get rid of that square.

[image]

Below is my custom bottom sheet sample

```
public abstract class EmployeeBottomSheetDialog extends BottomSheetDialog {

    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;
    private RecyclerView employeeRecyclerView;
    private EditText searchEditText;
    private DataBase dataBase;
    private ArrayList<Employe> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Employe> employeeSelectedList = new ArrayList<>();
    private SelectEmployeeAdapter selectEmployeeAdapter;
    private ImageButton closeSearchImageButton;

    public EmployeeBottomSheetDialog(@NonNull Context context, List<Employe> selectedEmployeeList) {
        super(context,R.style.BottomSheetDialogStyle);
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = (Activity) context;
        if(!selectedEmployeeList.isEmpty()){
            employeeSelectedList.clear();
            employeeSelectedList.addAll(selectedEmployeeList);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.employee_bottom_sheet_dialog);
    }
}
```

Below is my style

```
 <style name="BottomSheetDialogStyle" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
        <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay</item>
        <item name="backgroundTint">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="background">@android:color/transparent</item>
 </style>
```

below is my bottom sheet layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialog_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_background"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_drop_down_24" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/between_two_views">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/search_wrapper"
                style="@style/textInputHint"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/search_employees">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/search"
                    style="@style/textInputText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/close_search"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_close_24"
                android:text="Button" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/employee_recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/between_two_views"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Below is my rounded corner drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="20dp" android:topRightRadius="20dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/red" />
</shape>
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but setting the style before `super.onCreate` might help, set it to null or something rather than material theme

Comment: I dont know how to do that, can you provide a code please??

Comment: I'm currently on my phone and it's a bit hard to type, but check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37104960/bottomsheetdialog-with-transparent-background) question. The answer shows how to set style

Comment: setStyle() is only for the BottomSheetDialogFragment not for the BottomSheetDialog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve this, you need a transparent background color in your dialog style (BottomSheetDialogStyle):

```
<item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <style name="BottomSheetStyle" parent="Theme.Design.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/Model</item>
</style>

<style name="Model" parent="Widget.Design.BottomNavigationView">
    <item name="background">@drawable/bottom_sheet_layout</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

I found out the answer after hours of searching. i only needed to use below style

```
  <style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppModalStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/bottom_sheet_background</item>
    </style>
```